# How to jump next tag in current buffer - vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to jump to next tag in current buffer?

```
sub A { 
  /* ... */
  [cursor]
}

sub B { /* ... */ }
```

I know both `A` and `B` are tags in current buffer.
Is there a way to jump to the next tag after `[cursor]`? (it would be `B` in this example).

Comment: I'm not aware that Vim is able to do that (out of the box), but `]]` would jump to `B` (and `[[` to `A`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you could implement this yourself:

You can obtain the list of all tags within the current buffer via

```
:let tags = filter(taglist('.*'), 'v:val.filename ==# expand("%:p")')
```

Then escape the tag names for use in a regular expression and join them as alternative search branches:

```
:let tagsExpr = '\V' . join(map(tags, 'escape(v:val.name, "\\")'), '\|')
```

Finally perform a search to locate the next tag in the current buffer:

```
:call search(tagsExpr)
```